# VBulletin 5.4.0 installation Error: 1071

Tags: php, mysql, vbulletin

Today I Was Installing Vbulletin For The First Time And During The Installation, It Gave This Error.

> Creating userchangelog table An error has occurred with your database.
>   Please contact vBulletin Support for assistance.
>
> Module: install, Step 3 Database Error:1071
>
> Specified key was too long; max key length is 1000 bytes
>
> Query:
>
> CREATE TABLE userchangelog (  changeid INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL
>   AUTO_INCREMENT,   userid INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',   fieldname
>   VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',     newvalue VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL
>   DEFAULT '',   oldvalue VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',  adminid INT
>   UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',    change_time INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL
>   DEFAULT '0',  change_uniq VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',    ipaddress
>   INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',    PRIMARY KEY  (changeid),    KEY
>   userid (userid,change_time),  KEY change_time (change_time),  KEY
>   change_uniq (change_uniq),    KEY fieldname (fieldname,change_time),
>     KEY adminid (adminid,change_time) ) ENGINE = MyISAM Status: Aborted
>
> Version
>  VBulletin: 5.4.0
>  PHP: 7.0
>  MYSQL: I Have No Idea!

Before The Installation, I Run A Script Called [vb_test.php](https://files.vbulletin.com/vb_test.zip) The Result Said That VBulletin 5.4.0 Can Run On This Server Without Any Error

Comment: What did vBulletin Support  say?

Answer (score 0):

From the failed error, it seems that you are using `MyISAM` engine. Better to change the default storage engine of the mysql server to `Innodb` and also set the `innodb_large_prefix` to ON.

To set the default storage engine and to enable innodb_large_prefix, you can add the below line in my.cnf

```
 default_storage_engine = innodb
 innodb_large_prefix = ON
```

After this, try to install and see if it works.